# JAX-RS, Jackson and JodaTime: not working automatic configuration

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, jodatime

I'm trying to create a simple REST service with JAX-RS (Jersey), without using Spring. And I'm using Joda as date fields in my entity.

To configure automatic json mapping, I create a JsonMapperProvider, where I add JodaModule:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonMapperProvider() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

This is my Resource class:

```
@Path("users")
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUserById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {

        return userService.findById(id);
    }
}
```

And I'm using a "no web.xml" configuration, with this class:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

}
```

But it doesn't work... the LocalDate field in User entity is always returned empty. 
The only workaround I found is to register all the components (including JacksonFeature class from jersey-media-json-jackson) in the ResourceConfig class, like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public RestApplication() {
        super(
                UserController.class,
                JsonMapperProvider.class,
                JacksonFeature.class
        );
    }
}
```

Is there another solution to this problem? I'd rather not to register all my services and other stuff in this class manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is how it's supposed to work.  You can also override the methods in `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` instead of extending `ResourceConfig`

Comment: Yes, I see. But the thing I don't like is: If I "manually" register the JacksonMapper (in ResourceConfig subclass constructor or Application methods), then I HAVE to register my Resource class, because, for some reason, when you create this constructor, the Resources and other stuff have to be registered "manually"...

By the way, I discovered a little improve for the manually registration, with this, it works:

 public RestApplication() {
        packages("com.edwise.pocs.jerseyrest");

        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }